# GNU Make is running out of memory using -j. What is it doing in that particular moment?

Tags: debugging, gnu-make

I'm running big GNU Make file with -j flag. At one point Make process overflows all RAM and falls with "segmentation fault". Without -j flag the process finish sucessufly. How to know what is GNU Make doing when it starting to eat memory? Debug flag (-d) not helping in this problem.

Comment: How do you know that Make allocate lot of RAM? If the processes it spawns takes up all RAM, I reckon that it could crash if the next malloc() returns 0. Have you tried to run with OOM-killer disabled (assuming that you are running under Linux)?

Comment: What is the exact command line you start make with?

Answer (score 1):

Are you perhaps running `gmake -j` without any argument for `-j`? In this case `gmake` runs as many processes in parallel as it can (which may be in the hundreds or thousands). This may very well lead to segfaults either in `gmake` or the forked processes. If that is the problem, limit the number of parallel processes with, say,

```
gmake -j 4
```

A rough estimate for the number is twice the number of CPU cores.

Answer (score 0):

if you run out of memory you should not get segmentation fault as error message. If some make process is eating a lot of memory, then crashing like that, it is probably a stack overflow.

Is it possible that the makefile has some kind of recursive dependency?

Comment: Yeah you right, time to time I'm not getting a "segFault" as error message, in this case I see only that the process is killed by system.

Comment: can't think of anything else right now. Can you add some more details of your situation?

Answer (score 0):

It is not GNU make that is eating memory. It is running the commands in various targets that get forked in parallel that are eating memory individually. That's probably why the problem only appears when you run with more than one parallel process. You have tried `-j2` and that fails also, right?

If you use [remake](http://bashdb.sf.net/remake), when your processes fail then you'll see the make command that failed along with target stack that got it called.